# How can I rename a key pair in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am using a key pair called 'newkey' on many instances. I **wish to keep using this key**, but change the name of the key pair (obviously 'newkey' is quite vague, and won't be new forever).

Please note: there are a lot of similar questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance, about changing the keypair on a running instance. This is a different topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot rename an existing keypair via the console or the API. You can [import an existing key pair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws), however, so you could delete they keypair and import it with a new name..